# Java inheritance with constructor

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, super

Hey guys so I am working on a simple java inheritance program with shapes. I know that my problem is nothing new but I've researched and the usual problem is that the super parameter is not matching the constructor parameter types of the parent class. However, I have matching parameters and still get this error. The error is occurring in the super statement in Parallelogram. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
public abstract class Quadrilateral implements Shapes
{
double base, height, perimeter, area, s1, s2, s3, s4;
String name;

 public Quadrilateral(String name, double base, double height, double side1, double side2, double side3, double side4){
   this.name = name;
   this.base = base;
   this.height = height;
   s1 = side1;
   s2 = side2;
   s3 = side3;
   s4 = side4;

}



public double getHeight(){
   return height;
}

public double getS1(){
    return s1;
}

public double getS2(){
    return s2;
}

public double getS3(){
    return s3;
}

public double getS4(){
    return s4;
}

public double getPerimeter(){
    return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
}

public String toString(){
    String str;
    str = "name is " + name + "\n";
    str += "area is " + area + "\n";
    str += "perimeter is " + perimeter + "\n";
    str += "sides 1-4 are " + s1 + ", " + s2 + ", " + s3 + "and " + s4;

    return str;
}
}
```

new class

```
public class Parallelogram extends Quadrilateral
{

public Parallelogram(String name, double base, double height){

super(name, side1, side2, side1, side1, side2, side2); //RECIEVE ERROR HERE WITH THE FIRST SIDE1!!!

}

public double getArea(){
area = base * height;
return area;    
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}


}
```

new class

```
public class Rectangle extends Parallelogram
{
 public Rectangle(String name, double side1, double side2){
     super(name, side1, side2);
    }
}
```

new class

```
public class Square extends Rectangle
{
public Square(String name, double side1){
    super(name, side1, side2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing values to the base constructor that aren't defined in the `Parallelogram` constructor - namely `side1` and `side2`.  One option is to change

```
public Parallelogram(String name, double base, double height){

super(name, side1, side2, side1, side1, side2, side2); //RECIEVE ERROR HERE WITH THE FIRST SIDE1!!!

}
```

to

```
public Parallelogram(String name, double base, double height, double side1, double side2){

super(name, base, height, side1, side1, side2, side2); 

}
```

and similarly for `Rectangle` and `Square`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you did not use the "this.s1" keyword in your Quadrilateral class?
Also, are you intending on declaring an abstract method at All in any of your sub-classes?

Also, you should get in the habit of declaring your instance variables to private, it's good practice and promotes data encapsulation (data hiding).

I think it would be a much nicer program if you have all your subclasses extend quadrilateral. Instead of quadrilateral extends parallelogram extends rectangle extends squares etc.
Enjoy!